# Filestream seeks correct position whereas fstream doesn't

Tags: c#, c++, boost

In C#

```
FileStream fs("file.bin",/*Open in binary, read only mode*/);
var bytes = new byte[100];
fs.Seek(20000000, SeekOrigin.Begin); //*20000000*
fs.Read(bytes, 0, 100);
```

in C++, `istream` always becomes `null`

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> FileStream;
FileStream fs = FileStream(new boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source("file.bin", 100, 0));

if (fs->is_open())
{
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> is(*fs.get());
    if (is.seekg(20000000, is.beg))
        //read 100 characters from 20000000th position
    fs->close();
}
```

if I change
`boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> is(*fs.get());`

into
`boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> is("file.bin");`

`is` is initialized but reading up to `20000000th` byte is still impossible. Error occurs exactly the same as when the file specified isn't found.

Comment: Have you tried using the vanilla C++ file streams? Unless there is a compulsion to use boost they might work better.

Comment: The idea is to use mapped file IO

Comment: current C++ and its libraries still disapoint  its users a lot

Comment: @user1458245 Before you start to compare C++ and C#, think a bit about the requirements for both languages. Also, don´t think problems in VS as problems of C++ in general, and Boost!=C++. (Also, like mentioned below, don´t think that the APIs are the same. If that was the error, reading the docs would´ve helped)

Comment: I haven't used `mapped_file_source` but it looks like the second parameter is the length of the part of the file to be mapped - you are passing 100 - so you wouldn't be able to read past 100 bytes.

Comment: Yes, that's correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are excplicitly telling the `mapped_file_source` that the maximum file size to be mapped is 100 bytes. So why would you think you could go into position 20000000 and read anything?

See the [reference on mapped_file_source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html)

> Overview: By default, files must exist before being opened, and are not truncated; attempting to write past the end of a file results in an error.
>
> Constructor documentation:
> length    -   The number of bytes to map. If this parameter is not specified, the entire file is mapped.

Comment: My file is 4MB but why can I not set the offset to 60000 ?
`FileStream fs = FileStream(new boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source("file.bin", 100, 50000));`

Comment: @user1458245 From documentation: "offset -  The offset where the mapping is to begin. This value must be a multiple of the operating system's virtual memory allocation granularity, which can be obtained using the static member function alignment."

Comment: Thanks, 
So according to the document, I have to do this `mapped_file_source(file.bin,100,50000*mapped_file_source::alignment())` ?????

This offset number becomes larger and thus it sure fails again.

Comment: @user1458245 No, you just have to make sure the start position is divisible with the alignment. For example, if the alignment is 4096 (just an example), you can only put the start at 49152 (12*4096) and then the data at position 50000 in the file is at position 848 in the stream. So basically the offset must be (50000/alignment)*alignment